# Parsing multilevel headers in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Trying my hands pandas multi level indexing. Have shown sample for input as well as output. I tried transposing, reading part by part, not sure where I am going incorrect:

Input:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['2016-11-21', '2016-11-22', '2016-11-23', '2016-11-24', '2016-11-25'],
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list('AB'), list('ab')]),
                  data=np.array([[2,3,5,6,6], [1,4,2,3,3], [3,1,1,1,0], [0,0,6,5,2]]).T)
print (df)
            A     B   
            a  b  a  b
2016-11-21  2  1  3  0
2016-11-22  3  4  1  0
2016-11-23  5  2  1  6
2016-11-24  6  3  1  5
2016-11-25  6  3  0  2
```

Desired Output:
I need to get value for '2016-11-22' across column a for both A and B

> ```
>      a
>  A   3
>  B   1
> ```

Answer (score 1):

to match your output you can use `df.xs` with `unstack`

```
df.xs('a',axis=1,level=1,drop_level=False).loc['2016-11-22'].unstack()
```

---

```
   a
A  3
B  1
```

however if you are interested for a single level and index , you could also try:

```
df.xs('a',axis=1,level=1).loc['2016-11-22']

A    3
B    1
Name: 2016-11-22, dtype: int64
```

Comment: nice one, first time actually seeing `xs` in use, I don't often work with multi indexes but when I do i'm amazed by flexibility of the API

Answer (score 1):

try `filter` and `.loc`

```
df.filter(like='2016-11-22',axis=0).loc[:,df.columns.get_level_values(1).isin(['a'])].stack(0)


          a
2016-11-22 A  3
           B  1
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the date index to find the row then a select the columns using a tuple pair matching the multi-index for all level 0 columns and only 'a' for level 1 columns

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['2016-11-21', '2016-11-22', '2016-11-23', '2016-11-24', '2016-11-25'],
              columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list('AB'), list('ab')]),
              data=np.array([[2,3,5,6,6], [1,4,2,3,3], [3,1,1,1,0], [0,0,6,5,2]]).T)

 columns=df.columns.levels[0]
 print(df.loc['2016-11-22',(columns,'a')])

 output:
 A  a    3
 B  a    1
 Name: 2016-11-22, dtype: int32
```